# Google Map does not display in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse

i am trying to run google map tutorial using following link
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

followed all steps but when i try to run this application it does not display anything except boxes and zooming button

can any one guide is there any thing i am missing?? i have obtained new google map key from google website too.

Comment: Sounds like it's just not loading the map tiles. Is your emulator able to access the internet? Can you access web pages from the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i got my answer,

i had not created MD5 Certificate thats why it was showing only boxes after create MD5 certificate everything is working fine.. :D 
the procedure is given below.......

keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore D:\Androidkeystore\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

if you have not set environment variables for java in your machine then above command wont work or you will have to go to the bin directy of your java folder in program files to run above command.

by copy pasting debug.keystore file from builtin folder to user friendly folder and ran it.

and finally i got the md5 certificate.

Comment: I also faced same issue. Where we need the MD5 certificate? Please tell me solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

yup this is a symptom of not having a google maps api key for your application.

As I'm sure your aware [you can find everything you need here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html) for obtaining a google maps api key.