# Google map not displayed in android

Tags: android

google map is not displayed ,in this i am generate new md5 key also but it is not coming.instead of map boxes and zoom buttons r coming

I am using this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/frame"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:apiKey="0Hk8f49CqFaKR6GAiakhaQ5qAbrmcWXM4WLjV1A"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the layout you are using.

Comment: Did you get an api-key from google?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Show us some code snippets and error messages if you are seeing any.

Comment: Assuming you have done everything correct; sometimes you have to wait for the map to show up especially if your internet speed is slow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show a map in an Android mapactivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097594/how-to-show-a-map-in-an-android-mapactivity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hi Sairam this was useful for me! 
step by step

[How-To-Set-Up-an-API-Key-for-Google-Map](http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a35/Android-How-To-Set-Up-an-API-Key-for-Google-Maps.html)

Jorgesys

Comment: If you think you've done everything right, as I did, pay particular attention to the adding of user permission described by the link above

Answer (score 1):

Why don't people ever search (or read [the directions](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html))? This has been covered exhaustively in the past... a [5-second Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=android+google+maps+blank+site%3Astackoverflow.com) of this site returned: [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809507/android-hello-mapview-tutorial-map-tiles-do-not-load),  [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091897/google-map-does-not-display-in-android),  [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887242/android-map-map-does-not-show-up-on-device), [Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097594/how-to-show-a-map-in-an-android-mapactivity)

Answer (score 1):

When exporting a project there is one field keystore there in that field give the path of the file where you have put that API key then it will work. I also have faced same problem and I had worked out for 4 days to reach that.

Answer (score 1):

Also,ensure that you are not behind a proxy.If you are behind a proxy server, your map will  not load.There is no problem with your layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you "did everything properly" it would be working. I gave you links to where this has been covered in-depth [the first time you asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100158/google-map-not-displayed-in-android).

Please stop posting the same question over and over again, this is the third time in less than 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

No need of creating a new keystore when we don't get the maps with the debug keystore u can delete it and and relaunch the eclipse this will create a new debug keystore.. but we have to newly create the application becausethe previous app will not work with the new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Following Link  is helpfull.

[This is the perfect link for begining of google map programs](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)